# Get page's blocks in EPiServer Content delivery API

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I have a page in Episerver / Optimizely, with a page that has some blocks, but I want to access the blocks through https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/57 (whith episerver content delivery api), but the blocks won't follow. Is it possible to return the blocks with the page?

Comment: Most probably you need to add `expand=*` - good reading on the topic https://www.jondjones.com/learn-optimizely/cms/how-to-enable-content-delivery-api-in-optimizely-cms-12/ under "Accessing the API" section

Answer (score 0):

This is an ODATA api, you'll need to tell it to expand the properties you want to see

To expand everything

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/57?expand=*
```

To expand a certain property

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/57?expand=propertyToExpand
```

Comma separate properties to expand if multiple

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/57?expand=propertyToExpand,otherPropertyToExpand
```

Optimize your query by using select (you should)

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/57?expand=propertyToExpand,otherPropertyToExpand&select=propertyToExpand,otherPropertyToExpand
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, for me using expand does work but I can't even access a page by calling its id. I get a 404 response from the call if I try something like:

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/5&expand=*
```

And if I try to call a none existing id, I get a 500 response.

But if I assign a friendly url (ie: `start`) to my page whose id is 5, I can call it through that:

```
https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content?ContentUrl=start&expand=*
```

Comment: Your first link is malformed. It should work fine if you change the '&' to an '?' like this:  
`https://localhost:5000/api/episerver/v3.0/content/5?expand=*` Otherwise it thinks the content reference id is `5&expand=*` and not just `5`.